# Make sure user entered correct type of data when using scanf()

Tags: objective-c, scanf

I'm using `scanf()` for user input:

```
- (void)setupUserData {
     NSLog(@"\nPlease enter an account number:");
     scanf("%i", &accountNumber);
     NSLog(@"\nPlease enter a bank balance");
     scanf("%f", &startBalance);
}
```

It works well when I enter an actual integer, but if I input a character, my code just breaks. Is there a way I can check what the user has typed, or to prevent the user from entering anything other than an integer?

Comment: You can check scanf ruturn value to determine if he inputed something illegal

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: Just google what scanf return!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) returns the number of arguments that were successfully filled. Since you're only filling 1 argument, a return value of 0 would indicate that the input was invalid.

**Example:**

```
if (scanf("%i", &accountNumber) == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Invalid account number");
}
```